# tkinter variable conversion on continuously changing analog values

Tags: python, tkinter

I have python code using tkinter that reads analog values and displays them on the screen every 100ms and it works great. However, I now need to convert these analog values to distance, and the way my code is written I am using lists and StringVar. I need to take the value and divide it by a number to get distance but the values I get are of the wrong type. I am new to python and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

This is my code:

```
# set global
regs_x = []
regs_y = []
# init a thread lock
regs_lock_x = Lock()
regs_lock_y = Lock()

def polling_thread():
    global regs_x, regs_y, regs_lock_x, regs_lock_y
    c = ModbusClient(host='192.168.1.50', port=502, auto_open=True)
    while True:
        # do modbus reading on socket
        reg_list_x = c.read_holding_registers(0, 1)
        reg_list_y = c.read_holding_registers(1, 1)
        # if read is ok, store result in regs (with thread lock)
        if reg_list_x:
            with regs_lock_x:
                #regs_x = list(reg_list_x)
                regs_x = reg_list_x
        if reg_list_y:
            with regs_lock_y:
                regs_y = list(reg_list_y)
        # 1s before next polling
        #time.sleep(1)


def get_analog_x():
    # print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
            with regs_lock_x:
                list_string_x = ''.join(map(str, regs_x))
                #print(list_string_x)
                analog_value_x.set(list_string_x)
            window.after(100, get_analog_x)

def get_analog_y():
    # print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
            with regs_lock_y:
                list_string_y = ''.join(map(str, regs_y))
                #print("".join(list_string_x)
                analog_value_y.set(list_string_y)
            window.after(100, get_analog_y)

# start x polling thread
tp = Thread(target=polling_thread)
# set daemon: polling thread will exit if main thread exit
tp.daemon = True
tp.start()


analog_value_x = IntVar()
analog_value_y = StringVar()

get_analog_x()
get_analog_y()
```

...
and I display the data using this line:

```
x_lvdt=Entry(window, width=5, justify=CENTER, font=('Arial 14'), textvariable=analog_value_x)
```

When I try and introduce code below all of the above code to convert the values to distance

```
int_x = analog_value_x.get()
print(int_x)
#print(int_x / 1290)
```

I get this error:

```
  int_x = analog_value_x.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 547, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

No matter what I try, I'm not able to turn the analog values into integers, and for some reason I'm getting back "", not a number. I do not know why, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to set `analg_value_x` to an empty string.  `regs_x` is an empty list, so `list_string_x` will be empty.  And note that because you now have `analog_value_x` as an `IntVar`,, you must `.set` it to an integer value, not a string as you are doing here.  Do you want that value in decimal, or in hex?

Comment: I want to display in decimal so I can divide by 1290 and turn that value into millimeters

Comment: I tried doing this:

int_x = int(analog_value_x.set())
#int_x = analog_value_x.get()
print(int_x)

but get this error:

 int_x = int(analog_value_x.set())
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Comment: I thought that since I have the function get_analog_x() that if I call it with a get/set I should get a value back? I was under the impression that the value for analog_value_x is being updated every 100ms, so why can't I access that data from the function? Why would list_string_x be empty? Aren't I getting it in a similar way using the Entry variable to display?

Comment: `list_string_x` is empty because `regs_x` is empty.  You don't show when you call `polling_thread`, but if `get_analog_x` gets called before `polling_thread` has had a chance to set `regs_x`, then you'll be setting an empty string.

Comment: post edited to show polling_thread. It is being called before get_analog_x is called

Comment: leaving analog_value_x = IntVar() still gives me the analog values every 100ms in the Entry

Comment: *It is being called before get_analog_x is called* -- No, it is not.  Its thread is being started before, but there is no guarantee that the code will run first.  Indeed, because of the way Python's threading works, it's almost certain you'll try to read those values before the thread code has run.  Perhaps you should initialize `regs_x` to some value that won't cause it to explode.

Comment: what if instead I do the math here ```analog_value_x.set(list_string_x)``` inside `get_analog_x()`. I know that it's a string value in a list so that would need to be sorted out. I tried initializing `regs_x` to a value, and that does work but the values never get updated

Comment: Look, none of us know what your ultimate goal is here.  If you don't need the literal holding register values, but you can compute something useful from them, then do the arithmetic in the polling thread.

Comment: My ultimate goal is instead of showing the analog values in the Entry, show the distance instead, which would involve dividing the Entry by a number. Thank you for your patience, I am new to python and trying to learn. I will try to do the math in the polling thread instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem. I have no idea if this is the best way but I instead converted the index 0 of the `regs_list_x` list into an `int` and did the math on it, no change to the other code as I wanted it to display in the same location. Now I'm displaying distance instead of analog values. Thank you all for your help and input on this issue

```
# set global
regs_x = ""
regs_y = []

#regs_x = np.array()
# init a thread lock
regs_lock_x = Lock()
regs_lock_y = Lock()

def polling_thread():
    global regs_x, regs_y, regs_lock_x, regs_lock_y
    c = ModbusClient(host='192.168.1.50', port=502, auto_open=True)
    while True:
        # do modbus reading on socket
        reg_list_x = c.read_holding_registers(0, 1)
        reg_list_y = c.read_holding_registers(1, 1)
        int_x = int(reg_list_x[0])
        # if read is ok, store result in regs (with thread lock)
        if reg_list_x:
            with regs_lock_x:
                ##regs_x = list(reg_list_x)
                regs_x = int_x/1290
                #regs_x = np.array(reg_list_x)
        if reg_list_y:
            with regs_lock_y:
                regs_y = list(reg_list_y)
        # 1s before next polling
        #time.sleep(1)


def get_analog_x():
    # print regs list (with thread lock synchronization)
            with regs_lock_x:
                #list_string_x = ''.join(map(str, regs_x))
                #list_int_x = list_string_x.translate("[]'")
                #list_int_x = list(map(int, list_string_x))
                ##print(list_string_x)
                analog_value_x.set(regs_x)
                #analog_value_x.set(int(list_int_x)/1290)
            window.after(100, get_analog_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest demostration of your issue is:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, IntVar

root= Tk()
int_var = IntVar()
int_var.set('')
int_var.get()
```

This would lead me to believe that this line:

```py
list_string_x = ''.join(map(str, regs_x))
```

is leaving list_string_x == '', which is not what you'd want.  you want to make sure that list_string_x is either an int (e.g. 0) or an int as a string (e.g. '0').  Not sure about the rest of your logic, but I suspect you want something like `regs_x = reg_list_x.copy()` up above, but I think the underlying issue is that `c.read_holding_registers(0, 1)` is returning an empty list or perhaps the
`get_analog_x()` is being called before the polling_thread is up and running.

Comment: I would like to mention that if I do not try and convert the analog value to an integer, I do get the analog values every 100ms and it works very well. The problem is that analog counts don't mean anything and I want it to display in distance. I just don't understand why in the Entry I can get analog_value_x, but I can't get that value elsewhere and convert it over to an int so I can do some simple math

Comment: @jeffg because you made it an IntVar and not a StringVar, then attempts to call get() will force an int conversion.   you can stick with StringVar and just do `int(my_string_var.get())` and then you do all the math you want.  Of course, if you set that StringVar to empty string '' you will get a ValueError exception just the same.  If you want to stick to IntVar you will have to fix the empty string issue, which seems you're not really accepting is happening, even though it's directly in the error message you posted.

Comment: I am accepting the empty string issue when trying to convert to an int. I just don't know why. I can get the values just fine and display them to the screen every 100ms, so why can't I convert those same values of analog_value_x to an int?

Comment: I'm suggesting it's a race condition somehow.  Are you saying that you can see that entry has data at the time that `analog_value_x.get()` is called?    what about calling `x_lvdt.get()` that should return the string version of what's inside the Entry widget (no int conversion done).  The last thing I'm thinking if it isn't a race condition is somehow the threading is somehow causing problems inside the tkinter library.

Comment: `x_lvdt.get()` returns empty. Somehow the first entry is empty maybe? I need to do math on the continuous changing value of analog_value_x, which I know is currently a string. Is there a way to change polling_thread() and get_analog_x() to give me an int instead of a list? I'm only pulling one value from each axis, do I need a list?